# Assistance with the following five star rating script

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Here the JavaScript and CSS are running smooth. but whenever I try to run the PHP file it shows an error stating undefined index like following:

```
Notice: Undefined index: do in C:\wamp\www\PROJECT\jquery_tutorial_starrating\update.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0016  375888  {main}( )   ..\update.php:0

Notice: Undefined index: do in C:\wamp\www\PROJECT\jquery_tutorial_starrating\update.php on line 14
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0016  375888  {main}( )   ..\update.php:0
```

my html code is:

```
    <html>
     <head> 

     <script src="rating/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
     <script src="rating/starrating.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
     <link href="rating/starrating.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
     </head> 
     <body> 
      <h2>Star Rater</h2> 
     <ul class='star-rating'> 
     <li class="current-rating" id="current-rating"><!-- will show current rating --></li> 
     <span id="ratelinks"> 
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="1 star out of 5" class="one-star">1</a></li> 
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="2 stars out of 5" class="two-stars">2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="3 stars out of 5" class="three-  stars">3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="4 stars out of 5" class="four-stars">4</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="5 stars out of 5" class="five-stars">5</a></li> 
    </span> 
    </ul>
</body> 
</html>
```

My starrating.css file:

```
/* CSS Document */

.star-rating,
.star-rating a:hover,
.star-rating a:active,
.star-rating .current-rating{
background: url(star.gif) left -1000px repeat-x;
}
.star-rating{
position:relative;
width:125px;
height:25px;
overflow:hidden;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-position: left top;
}
.star-rating li{
display: inline;
}
.star-rating a,
.star-rating .current-rating{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
text-indent:-1000em;
height:25px;
line-height:25px;
outline:none;
overflow:hidden;
border: none;
}
.star-rating a:hover,
.star-rating a:active{
background-position: left bottom;
}
.star-rating a.one-star{
width:20%;
z-index:6;
}
.star-rating a.two-stars{
width:40%;
z-index:5;
}
.star-rating a.three-stars{
width:60%;
z-index:4;
}
.star-rating a.four-stars{
width:80%;
z-index:3;
}
.star-rating a.five-stars{
width:100%;
z-index:2;
}
.star-rating .current-rating{
z-index:1;
background-position: left center;
}
```

my starrating.js file-

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get current rating
    getRating();
    // get rating function
    function getRating(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "update.php",
            data: "do=getrate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // apply star rating to element
                $("#current-rating").css({ width: "" + result + "%" });
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }

    // link handler
    $('#ratelinks li a').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "update.php",
            data: "rating="+$(this).text()+"&do=rate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // remove #ratelinks element to prevent another rate
                $("#ratelinks").remove();
                // get rating after click
                getRating();
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php
// connect to database
$dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "abc", "") or die ('Cannot connect to the database');
mysql_select_db ("star",$dbh);



if($_GET['do']=='rate')
{

// do rate
rate();
}
else if($_GET['do']=='getrate')
{
// get rating
getRating();
}

// function to retrieve
function getRating(){

$sql= "select * from vote";
$result=@mysql_query($sql);
$rs=@mysql_fetch_array($result);
// set width of star
$rating = (@round($rs[value] / $rs[counter],1)) * 20; 
echo $rating;
}

// function to insert rating
function rate(){
$text = strip_tags($_GET['rating']);
$update = "update vote set counter = counter + 1, value = value +    ".$_GET['rating']."";

$result = @mysql_query($update); 
if(@mysql_affected_rows() == 0){
    $insert = "insert into vote (counter,value) values     ('1','".$_GET['rating']."')";
    $result = @mysql_query($insert); 
}
}
?>
```

In the PHP file it shows the particular above mentioned errors.

Also I would like to set a function regarding the rating would be given by only those who are registered on the site.

Comment: PHP emits warnings if you try to access an array index that does not exist. Rather than `$_GET['do']=='rate'`, try `isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do']=='rate'`, and ditto for the other array access too.

Comment: Also, `strip_tags` isn't safe to prevent SQL injection; use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead. Better still, switch to PDO or mysqli and use parameterisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `@$_GET['do']` instead of `$_GET['do']`

Comment: can you please tell me what is the use of @ in @$_GET['do']

Comment: See here, it will suppress the error messages:

http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/07/php-the-operator/